# Time for some [myth] busting?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Some uses of the tag [myth](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myth) seem to be about mythology, whereas other uses seem to be just saying something's not true. Should questions that are about mythology be tagged [mythology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mythology) instead, and ones where it's just about a false rumour have the tag removed?

Comment: "False rumours" (as you put it) could be retagged [legends](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legends) but thats still a bit of a metatag

Comment: myth is a meta tag. Mythology is a meaningful tag. Use them as you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions retagged and tag blacklisted

Comment: shouldnt [tag:myth] just be a synonym of [tag:legend]?

Comment: @Jamiec if we did that, then everytime someone tags something as a myth because they have a bias, we'd end up with a new legend question. People can still use mythology for questions about legends.

Comment: hmm, perhaps - but thats just a straight up mistagging! In english the word "myth" is literally a synonym of "legend" http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/myth

Comment: However it's really bad to tag questions based on their perceived truthfulness (i.e. tagging a questions about NY sewer crocs as "myth" or "legend" sort-a sucks).

Comment: @Jamiec:FWIW,  [Not a exact synonym](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Legend_vs_Myth) but differences fall back to the same "perceived truthfulness" issue that Sklivvz mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I say go for it! There are such a small number of [myth](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myth) questions that a retag is easy. Votes on your question seem to agree.

Anything that aids in better categorizing questions is usually a good move.